# dynamic HTML page to pdf

Tags: html, pdf, converters

I know there is a list of similar questions but all handle pages without user interaction (static even though some js may be there).

Let's say we've a page the user can interact (e.g. svg than changes, or html tables with drilldown - content changes). Those interactions will change the page. Same happens in stackoverflow when entering the question...

The idea is adding a button, "convert to pdf" taking the state of the html and sending to the user back a pdf version (we've a Java server).

Using the print of the browser is not the answer I'm looking for :-).

Is this a stick in the moon ?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to store the parameters that generate the HTML view (i.e. what the user clicks on, what selections they make, etc). If you can have a list of parameters that generate the HTML view, you can have a method which accepts the list of parameters (JSON post?), generates the HTML view and passes it to your PDF generating routine. I'm not too familiar with Java libraries for this purpose, but PHP has TCPDF can take html output to basically generate a PDF for you. Certainly, there are Java libraries which will allow you to do the same thing, or you can use the parameters to get a list of rows/arrays which can be iterated over and output using the PDF library of your choice.

Comment: The problem is that user interaction is not really parameters (url) but interactions. In example, the text I'm adding as a comment would be added to the "to PDF"....weird I agree :-)

Comment: They don't have to be parameters necessarily for the display, but you would need equivalent parameters for it so that the interactions can be converted to such(i.e, search=Search%20for%20this&expanded_categories=1,2,5,20&....). You can then, using the parameters, generate the same display, restriction, page, etc, in memory and work with the PDF library.

Answer (score 1):

Both **iTextPDF** and **Aspose.PDF** would allow you to do that (I've seen them used in two different projects), but ***there is no magic and you will have to do some work***.

The steps are roughly:

1. Get (as a string) the part of the document which you want to print with jQuery or innerHTML
2. Call a service on the server side to convert this to PDF
3. [Serverside] Use a whitlist - based tool to clean up the hmtl (unless you want to be hacked). **JSoup** is great for that.
4. [Serverside] Use IText or Aspose API to create the PDF from the HTML (this is not trivial, you will have to read the doc)
5. Download the document

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend DocRaptor, an HTML to PDF API built by my company, Expected Behavior.

DocRaptor uses Prince XML to generate PDFs, and thus produces higher quality results than similar products.

Adding PDF generation to your own web application using our service is as simple as making an HTTP POST request to our server.

Here's a link to DocRaptor's home page:

[DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/)

And a link to our API documentation:

[DocRaptor API documentation](http://docraptor.com/documentation/)

Comment: we need a solution that can work offline (without connection to your server)