# creating page counter for dynamic html pdf

Tags: javascript, html, react-native

I'm trying to create a page counter for a dynamic HTML pdf and my code is

```css
.page-number:before {
    counter-increment: pages;
    content: " ";
}

.page-number:after {
    counter-increment: page;
}

.page-number:after {
    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
}
```

```html
<div>//some content</div>
<div class="page-number"></div>
```

but it will always print as "Page 1 of 1" for every page. Can someone point out the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Check this if it is helpfull  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706480/dynamic-html-page-to-pdf

Comment: the link is for converting to pdf, what im trying to do is basically creating a page counter for the converted pdf

Answer (score 1):

CSS Counter is not meant to get a total of elements.

You can still get it if you duplicate the HTML, like so :

```css
/** use this div as a total counter **/
#pageCounter {
  counter-reset: pageTotal;
}
#pageCounter span {
  counter-increment: pageTotal; 
}


/** and this one for the current page **/
#pageNumbers {
  counter-reset: pageCurrent;
}
#pageNumbers div:before { 
  counter-increment: pageCurrent; 
  content: "Page " counter(pageCurrent) " of "; 
}
#pageNumbers div:after { 
  content: counter(pageTotal); 
}
```

```html
<div id="pageCounter">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>

<div id="pageNumbers">
  <div class="page-number"></div>
  <div class="page-number"></div>
  <div class="page-number"></div>
  <div class="page-number"></div>
</div>
```

I'd recommend not to, and use javascript to count and display.

Comment: thats the thing. If I do it like this, every page will have the same result. What I wanna do is, create a single line of variable that later on will display the number of current pages with the total pages in each of the pages. Is it impossible to do so? I've looked everywhere and each given almost the same answer. anyway thank you for your time kind sir

Comment: If you run the code snippet you can see that it will display the total pages, maybe you want something else ? my pleasure